# Server error when trying to view revision histories of some old orphaned tag wikis (as a mod)

Tags: bug, moderators, tag-wiki, 500-server-error, orphaned-wiki

When looking at orphaned tag wikis via the moderator-only page (`/admin/orphan-wikis`), I found some that give 500 errors:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/4382/revisions
- https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/2142/revisions

There are more but I think you get the point. Apparently, it works in incognito, so maybe it's because I'm a mod on these sites.

Also I noticed the "help" is awkwardly phrased (presumably "orphan" should be plural):

> This lists all tag wikis that are **orphan**. Merging tags may create them.

Comment: Or orphan*ed*...

Comment: No repro, I can see those two just fine. Try to visit them while logged off or Incognito mode, maybe it happens only to mods.

Comment: I see where this is happening, and it is only for mods. I was hoping it was a database thing I could fix but, it's definitely app code, and I've flagged engineering.